# linux - add a password to a user that already has ssh authentication

Tags: linux, password

I have a user account on my server to which i access through ssh key authentication.
I want to give a temporary access to that account to a third person.
I was planning to create a password as an alternative authentication method (hence the server will be accessible either by password or by ssh key), give it to that third person for her to perform a job, and then delete the password once the job is done.

How can i create (and then delete) such a password?

Comment: Is there something restraining you from simply creating a new account for this person? User accounts should be personal.

Comment: I think it would be much better to just add another public key to `authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to the password question is:

- Edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to ensure that passwords are enabled.

---

```
PasswordAuthentication yes 
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

Then restart the ssh service (HT - @tonioc).  This will work for sysvinit systems:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

And this should work for systemd systems:

```
systemctl restart ssh
```

And then either:

- Login with your key and change the passwd of the account if the password is locked.

Or (better):

- Add a new user account for the new user and add that user to whatever minimum groups are required to accomplish the new user's task.

Or (even better):

- Add a new user and have them give you a public key
- Add their key to their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file if they don't know how to copy it themselves.

However, for the least number of changes but rather poor security, you can simply add another key to:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

on the server.

You can have as many keys as you want in the authorized_keys file.  It's one key per line with options prepended.

There are many options that can be added to the `authorized_keys` file.

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/142997/what-options-can-be-put-into-a-ssh-authorized-keys-file#143004)

And/or:

```
man authorized_keys
```

Of course, as others have pointed out, it's not a good idea to have more than one user per account unless it's run by a team.  Temporary privileged access or accounts are probably not a good idea.

Comment: But don't forget to delete it afterwards.

Comment: @Nick ... well, yeah... but if the account is the same, then there's nothing stopping the 2nd authorized user from modifying the account.  I didn't comment on the "goodness" of the idea -- which isn't too good. If I were to advise on a plan, I would say "add a new unprivileged account," but I don't know the purpose of the 2nd user login.

Comment: @RubberStamp Thx for your answer - but how to create a _password_ instead of a second ssh key?

Comment: @jimbasquiat:  Now I see what you mean.

Comment: @RubberStamp thx a lot - last question where is the sshd_config located?

Comment: @jimbasquiat changed answer to show /etc/ssh/sshd_config ... btw: unless I'm mistaken, which happens, I believe keys can only have one passphrase.  You can share the passphrase, of course.

Comment: @RubberStamp: I agree. BTW, nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

1) in sshd_config, add PasswordAuthentication method for this user:

```
Match User <thisusername>
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

then restart sshd service.

2) set the password for this user using (as root or with sudo):

```
passwd <thisusername>
```

once job is done, change PasswordAuthentication to no in sshd_config, and (optionally) change password using passwd again.

Comment: thx - how would you restart the ssh service?